# R 3.1.0 How to make a function to select between 2 columns (subsetting or indexing) using 1 argument?

Tags: r, subset

I need to get the mean (and remove all the NA values) of a particular "fruit" within a range of IDs or just one ID (The ID are from the farms the fruits are from).

This is my formatted data:

```
date         mangos papayas id
2010-04-17   20     30      2
2012-02-17   40     22      3
```

I have a folder called: "fruits". Then i have created this variable: "files_full"

files_full <- list.files("fruits", full.names = TRUE) # it contains: chr 1:32.
Now i. I have create a data frame: "dat" (dat <- data.frame())

What i need is to create a function with 3 arguments: **directory, fruit, id**. I have this function for that:

```
fruit <- function (directory, fruit, id) {
 files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE)
 dat <- data.frame()
 for (i in **id**){
   dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
    dat_subset <- subset (dat, dat$ID == id && dat$papaya == fruit|dat$mango == fruit)
    mean(data_subset)
 }
}
```

So:

1) Users will need to enter: directory, fruit, and id (for the farm the fruits are from, i          have a csv file for everyone of the 32 farms, thats why im doing a loop to combine them into a data frame (dat)).

2) My question: How to subset for a specific fruit. Let's say i have 2 columns: papayas, mangos. But only 1 argument: "fruit". AS you see i have tried something but not sure if it is OK.

After, subsetting or indexing the fruit and Id(s) i need to have the median of that    values.

So the **desire oput** would by something like:

```
fruit("fruits", "papayas", 2:3)

[1] 26
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple idea is that you use the name of the column to choose the column. For example: `df[[myFruit]]` where `myFruit <- "mango"` (say).

I think this should work. Give it a spin:

```
my_fun <- function (dir, fruit, id) {
  files_list <- list.files(dir, full.names = TRUE)
  dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files_list, read.csv))
  dat <- complete.cases(dat) # Remove any row that has NAs.
  return(mean(dat[dat[["id"]] %in% id, fruit]))
}
```

You should add the requirement for removing NAs directly into your question.

Comment: This is for the R language? I see some characters like "=", instead of "<-". Thanks!

Comment: I get: NaN... how can i make to remove all NA values in the data frame, within this function?

Comment: :D. I should have been consistent. But yes, both are valid.

Comment: please, explain to me, where in the function do we create the frame where we join all the CSV files into 1 file... so we can apply subsetting or indexing on it? I see you use "read.csv" but not any argument for that... I didn't mention it, but i have a folder with 332 csv files, and i need to join them... so users can enter for the argument ID == 1:222 for example.

Comment: Hi, the `do.call(rbind, ...)` is the part where we put everything into one data.frame.